# String Formating In/out using %s

Tags: python, string, numpy, scipy

I have the following statement that I can't seem to find the problem:

```
Analysis = 'Trythis'
TestName = 'ThisOne'
NumberIteration = 25

for num in range(NumberIteration):
    x= np.loadtxt("%s/results/data_%s/Outputs/$s/%sLCOE.txt" % (Analysis, num , TestName, TestName))
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
  np.loadtxt("%s/results/data_%s/Outputs/$s/%sLCOE.txt" % (Analysis, TestName, TestName, TestName)) 
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have tried to use `%d` and `%c`  instead of `%s`.  Does numpy have a problem using '_' before using a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is complaining that you gave four arguments to `%` but only have three `%s` in your format string.

I think the `$s` is meant to be a `%s`:

```
x= np.loadtxt("%s/results/data_%s/Outputs/%s/%sLCOE.txt" % (Analysis, num, TestName, TestName))
#                                         ^^
```

Note however that in modern Python code, you should be using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead:

```
x= np.loadtxt("{}/results/data_{}/Outputs/{}/{}LCOE.txt".format(Analysis, num, TestName, TestName))
```